# DB2 online backup not working and can't force the application

Tags: db2, backup, tablespace

I've started full online backup of DB2 database (primary on HADR) on NFS. The db is about 3 TB.
From the beginnig it's 0% of work completed.

And I can't find the application responsible for backup:

```
db2 list applications show detail | grep -i backup
```

I hit Ctrl+C, but it's still listed in the db2 list utilities (even after 13hrs it's 0%).

Because of the backup the tablespaces are in the 0x0800 State.

What is the resolution of this riddle? How can I cancel this backup without stopping the instance and make the tablepaces back to 0x0000 state?

I've tried to takeover HADR with Standby server to Primary, but it didn't responded, possibly because of 0x0800 states of tablespaces.

Regards

***db2pd -uti***

```
Database Member 0 -- Active -- Up 59 days 21:12:12 -- Date 2023-02-04-13.11.23.647422

Utilities:
Address            ID         Type                   State      Invoker    Priority   StartTime           DBName   NumPhases  CurPhase   Description
0x078000000800EB40 18236      BACKUP                 0          0          0          Fri Feb  3 20:05:13 DB_NAME 1           1           online db

Progress:
Address            ID         PhaseNum   CompletedWork                TotalWork                    StartTime           Description
0x078000000800F008 18236      1          0 bytes                      3203172077568 bytes          Fri Feb  3 20:05:13 n/a
```

**And the output of the db2diag.log after executing the backup:**

```
2023-02-03-20.05.13.038004+060 E1202639A533         LEVEL: Info
PID     : 31982054             TID : 14137          PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: inst_name              NODE : 000           DB   : DBNAME
APPHDL  : 0-39477              APPID: *LOCAL.inst_name.230203190514
AUTHID  : inst_name              HOSTNAME: primary
EDUID   : 14137                EDUNAME: db2agent (DBNAME) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqluxGetDegreeParallelism, probe:558
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Autonomic backup/restore - using parallelism = 10.

2023-02-03-20.05.13.824937+060 E1203173A560         LEVEL: Info
PID     : 31982054             TID : 14137          PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: inst_name              NODE : 000           DB   : DBNAME
APPHDL  : 0-39477              APPID: *LOCAL.inst_name.230203190514
AUTHID  : inst_name              HOSTNAME: primary
EDUID   : 14137                EDUNAME: db2agent (DBNAME) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqluxGetAvailableHeapPages, probe:634
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Autonomic BAR - heap consumption.
Targetting (50%) - 262144 of 524288 pages.

PID     : 31982054             TID : 14137          PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: inst_name              NODE : 000           DB   : DBNAME
APPHDL  : 0-39477              APPID: *LOCAL.inst_name.230203190514
AUTHID  : inst_name              HOSTNAME: primary
EDUID   : 14137                EDUNAME: db2agent (DBNAME) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqluxGetDegreeParallelism, probe:558
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Autonomic backup/restore - using parallelism = 10.

2023-02-03-20.05.13.824937+060 E1203173A560         LEVEL: Info
PID     : 31982054             TID : 14137          PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: inst_name              NODE : 000           DB   : DBNAME
APPHDL  : 0-39477              APPID: *LOCAL.inst_name.230203190514
AUTHID  : inst_name              HOSTNAME: primary
EDUID   : 14137                EDUNAME: db2agent (DBNAME) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqluxGetAvailableHeapPages, probe:634
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Autonomic BAR - heap consumption.
Targetting (50%) - 262144 of 524288 pages.

2023-02-03-20.05.13.825914+060 E1203734A547         LEVEL: Info
PID     : 31982054             TID : 14137          PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: inst_name              NODE : 000           DB   : DBNAME
APPHDL  : 0-39477              APPID: *LOCAL.inst_name.230203190514
AUTHID  : inst_name              HOSTNAME: primary
EDUID   : 14137                EDUNAME: db2agent (DBNAME) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqlubTuneBuffers, probe:889
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Autonomic backup - tuning enabled.
Using buffer size = 4097, number = 20.

INSTANCE: inst_name              NODE : 000           DB   : DBNAME
APPHDL  : 0-39477              APPID: *LOCAL.inst_name.230203190514
AUTHID  : inst_name              HOSTNAME: primary
EDUID   : 14137                EDUNAME: db2agent (DBNAME) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqluxGetAvailableHeapPages, probe:634
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Autonomic BAR - heap consumption.
Targetting (50%) - 262144 of 524288 pages.

2023-02-03-20.05.13.825914+060 E1203734A547         LEVEL: Info
PID     : 31982054             TID : 14137          PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: inst_name              NODE : 000           DB   : DBNAME
APPHDL  : 0-39477              APPID: *LOCAL.inst_name.230203190514
AUTHID  : inst_name              HOSTNAME: primary
EDUID   : 14137                EDUNAME: db2agent (DBNAME) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqlubTuneBuffers, probe:889
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Autonomic backup - tuning enabled.
Using buffer size = 4097, number = 20.

2023-02-03-20.05.13.868295+060 E1204282A493         LEVEL: Info
PID     : 31982054             TID : 14137          PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: inst_name              NODE : 000           DB   : DBNAME
APPHDL  : 0-39477              APPID: *LOCAL.inst_name.230203190514
AUTHID  : inst_name              HOSTNAME: primary
EDUID   : 14137                EDUNAME: db2agent (DBNAME) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqlubSetupJobControl, probe:2066
MESSAGE : Starting an online db backup.

2023-02-03-23.13.48.244675+060 E1204776A430         LEVEL: Info
PID     : 31982054             TID : 12081          PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: inst_name              NODE : 000           DB   : DBNAME
HOSTNAME: primary
EDUID   : 12081                EDUNAME: db2logmgr (DBNAME) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, data protection services, sqlpgArchiveLogFile, probe:3108
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Started archive for log file S0048345.LOG.
```

***db2pd -db DBNAME -apinfo 39477***

```
Database Member 0 -- Database DBANME -- Active -- Up 60 days 00:21:25 -- Date 2023-02-04-16.20.38.252022

snapapp Time:   2023-02-04-16.20.38.253042

Application :
  Address :                0x0A0001001470ECE0
  AppHandl [nod-index] :   39477    [000-39477]
  TranHdl :                692
  Application PID :        11600524
  Application Node Name :  primary
  IP Address:              n/a
  Connection Start Time :  2023-02-03-20.05.13.035704
  Client User ID :         instname
  System Auth ID :         instname
  Coordinator EDU ID :     14137
  Coordinator Member :     0
  Registered Agents :      1
  Active Agents :          1
  Locks timeout value :    NotSet
  Locks Escalation :       No
  Workload ID :            1
  Workload Occurrence ID : 1951323
  Trusted Context :        n/a
  Connection Trust Type :  non trusted
  Role Inherited :         n/a
  Application Status :     RequestInterrupted
  Application Name :       db2bp
  Application ID :         *LOCAL.instname.230203190514
  ClientUserID :           n/a
  ClientWrkstnName :       n/a
  ClientApplName :         n/a
  ClientAccntng :          n/a
  CollectActData:          N
  CollectActPartition:     C
  SectionActuals:          N
  UOW start time :         2023-02-03-20.05.13.037338
  UOW stop time :

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

***db2pd -db DBNAME -barstats 14137***

```
Printing out Backup Runtime Statistics at 2023-02-04-16.23.20.523322:


Backup Related EDUs:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
           Backup agent ID: 14137
           MC 0 (EDU ID): db2med.14137.0 (70333)


Table Spaces to be Backed Up (appTblSpace):
---------------------------------------------------------------------
      numEntry: 14

        Table Spaces:

              tblSpaceName: SYSCATSPACE
                tblSpaceID: 0
              tblSpaceType: 2
          tblSpaceDataType: 0
              tblSpaceSize: 28420 (in 4K pages)
               nContainers: 1
  backupInProgressTurnedOn: T
         backupActiveIsSet: T
    autoResizeLockAcquired: T
extentMovementLockAcquired: T
           olbLockAcquired: F
             userSpecified: T
        tblSpaceTotalPages: 28668
                  pageSize: 32768
                   extSize: 4
                actualSize: 931266560
                 scanPages: T
                 backupLSN: 0000000000000000

              tblSpaceName: USERSPACE1
                tblSpaceID: 2
              tblSpaceType: 2
          tblSpaceDataType: 32
              tblSpaceSize: 29457664 (in 4K pages)
               nContainers: 1
  backupInProgressTurnedOn: T
         backupActiveIsSet: T
    autoResizeLockAcquired: T
extentMovementLockAcquired: T
           olbLockAcquired: F
             userSpecified: T
        tblSpaceTotalPages: 29458016
                  pageSize: 32768
                   extSize: 32
                actualSize: 965268733952
                 scanPages: T
                 backupLSN: 0000000000000000

              tblSpaceName: SYSTOOLSPACE
                tblSpaceID: 3
              tblSpaceType: 2
          tblSpaceDataType: 32
              tblSpaceSize: 1652 (in 4K pages)
               nContainers: 1
  backupInProgressTurnedOn: T
         backupActiveIsSet: T
    autoResizeLockAcquired: T
extentMovementLockAcquired: T
           olbLockAcquired: F
             userSpecified: T
        tblSpaceTotalPages: 2044
                  pageSize: 32768
                   extSize: 4
                actualSize: 54132736
                 scanPages: T
                 backupLSN: 0000000000000000

              tblSpaceName: SL
                tblSpaceID: 4
              tblSpaceType: 2
          tblSpaceDataType: 32
              tblSpaceSize: 4512 (in 4K pages)
               nContainers: 1
  backupInProgressTurnedOn: T
         backupActiveIsSet: T
    autoResizeLockAcquired: T
extentMovementLockAcquired: T
           olbLockAcquired: F
             userSpecified: T
        tblSpaceTotalPages: 4832
                  pageSize: 32768
                   extSize: 32
                actualSize: 147849216
                 scanPages: T
                 backupLSN: 0000000000000000

              tblSpaceName: MONITOR
                tblSpaceID: 5
              tblSpaceType: 2
          tblSpaceDataType: 32
              tblSpaceSize: 3712 (in 4K pages)
               nContainers: 1
  backupInProgressTurnedOn: T
         backupActiveIsSet: T
    autoResizeLockAcquired: T
extentMovementLockAcquired: T
           olbLockAcquired: F
             userSpecified: T
        tblSpaceTotalPages: 4128
                  pageSize: 32768
                   extSize: 32
                actualSize: 121634816
                 scanPages: T
                 backupLSN: 0000000000000000

              tblSpaceName: XMLSPACE1
                tblSpaceID: 6
              tblSpaceType: 2
          tblSpaceDataType: 32
              tblSpaceSize: 57837504 (in 4K pages)
               nContainers: 1
  backupInProgressTurnedOn: T
         backupActiveIsSet: T
    autoResizeLockAcquired: T
extentMovementLockAcquired: T
           olbLockAcquired: F
             userSpecified: T
        tblSpaceTotalPages: 57837600
                  pageSize: 32768
                   extSize: 32
                actualSize: 1895219331072
                 scanPages: T
                 backupLSN: 0000000000000000

              tblSpaceName: INDSPACE1
                tblSpaceID: 7
              tblSpaceType: 2
          tblSpaceDataType: 32
              tblSpaceSize: 32384 (in 4K pages)
               nContainers: 1
  backupInProgressTurnedOn: T
         backupActiveIsSet: T
    autoResizeLockAcquired: T
extentMovementLockAcquired: T
           olbLockAcquired: F
             userSpecified: T
        tblSpaceTotalPages: 32512
                  pageSize: 32768
                   extSize: 32
                actualSize: 1061158912
                 scanPages: T
                 backupLSN: 0000000000000000

              tblSpaceName: ARCHSPACE1
                tblSpaceID: 8
              tblSpaceType: 2
          tblSpaceDataType: 32
              tblSpaceSize: 9817120 (in 4K pages)
               nContainers: 1
  backupInProgressTurnedOn: T
         backupActiveIsSet: T
    autoResizeLockAcquired: T
extentMovementLockAcquired: T
           olbLockAcquired: F
             userSpecified: T
        tblSpaceTotalPages: 9817760
                  pageSize: 32768
                   extSize: 32
                actualSize: 321687388160
                 scanPages: T
                 backupLSN: 0000000000000000

              tblSpaceName: DSMSPACE
                tblSpaceID: 9
              tblSpaceType: 2
          tblSpaceDataType: 32
              tblSpaceSize: 160 (in 4K pages)
               nContainers: 1
  backupInProgressTurnedOn: T
         backupActiveIsSet: T
    autoResizeLockAcquired: T
extentMovementLockAcquired: T
           olbLockAcquired: F
             userSpecified: T
        tblSpaceTotalPages: 160
                  pageSize: 32768
                   extSize: 32
                actualSize: 5242880
                 scanPages: T
                 backupLSN: 0000000000000000

              tblSpaceName: DLSPACE
                tblSpaceID: 11
              tblSpaceType: 2
          tblSpaceDataType: 32
              tblSpaceSize: 301504 (in 4K pages)
               nContainers: 1
  backupInProgressTurnedOn: T
         backupActiveIsSet: T
    autoResizeLockAcquired: T
extentMovementLockAcquired: T
           olbLockAcquired: F
             userSpecified: T
        tblSpaceTotalPages: 302048
                  pageSize: 32768
                   extSize: 32
                actualSize: 9879683072
                 scanPages: T
                 backupLSN: 0000000000000000

              tblSpaceName: DLSPACECOPY
                tblSpaceID: 12
              tblSpaceType: 2
          tblSpaceDataType: 32
              tblSpaceSize: 96 (in 4K pages)
               nContainers: 1
  backupInProgressTurnedOn: T
         backupActiveIsSet: T
    autoResizeLockAcquired: T
extentMovementLockAcquired: T
           olbLockAcquired: F
             userSpecified: T
        tblSpaceTotalPages: 992
                  pageSize: 32768
                   extSize: 32
                actualSize: 3145728
                 scanPages: T
                 backupLSN: 0000000000000000

              tblSpaceName: REPORTS
                tblSpaceID: 13
              tblSpaceType: 2
          tblSpaceDataType: 32
              tblSpaceSize: 64352 (in 4K pages)
               nContainers: 1
  backupInProgressTurnedOn: T
         backupActiveIsSet: T
    autoResizeLockAcquired: T
extentMovementLockAcquired: T
           olbLockAcquired: F
             userSpecified: T
        tblSpaceTotalPages: 64352
                  pageSize: 32768
                   extSize: 32
                actualSize: 2108686336
                 scanPages: T
                 backupLSN: 0000000000000000

              tblSpaceName: HISTORY
                tblSpaceID: 14
              tblSpaceType: 2
          tblSpaceDataType: 32
              tblSpaceSize: 3680 (in 4K pages)
               nContainers: 1
  backupInProgressTurnedOn: T
         backupActiveIsSet: T
    autoResizeLockAcquired: T
extentMovementLockAcquired: T
           olbLockAcquired: F
             userSpecified: T
        tblSpaceTotalPages: 4064
                  pageSize: 32768
                   extSize: 32
                actualSize: 120586240
                 scanPages: T
                 backupLSN: 0000000000000000

              tblSpaceName: DLSPACECOPY2
                tblSpaceID: 15
              tblSpaceType: 2
          tblSpaceDataType: 32
              tblSpaceSize: 161600 (in 4K pages)
               nContainers: 1
  backupInProgressTurnedOn: T
         backupActiveIsSet: T
    autoResizeLockAcquired: T
extentMovementLockAcquired: T
           olbLockAcquired: F
             userSpecified: T
        tblSpaceTotalPages: 161760
                  pageSize: 32768
                   extSize: 32
                actualSize: 5291114496
                 scanPages: T
                 backupLSN: 0000000000000000

        Table Space Queue:

[0]
                        tblSpaceName: XMLSPACE1
                          tblSpaceID: 6
                        backupStatus: pending

[1]
                        tblSpaceName: USERSPACE1
                          tblSpaceID: 2
                        backupStatus: pending

[2]
                        tblSpaceName: ARCHSPACE1
                          tblSpaceID: 8
                        backupStatus: pending

[3]
                        tblSpaceName: DLSPACE
                          tblSpaceID: 11
                        backupStatus: pending

[4]
                        tblSpaceName: DLSPACECOPY2
                          tblSpaceID: 15
                        backupStatus: pending

[5]
                        tblSpaceName: REPORTS
                          tblSpaceID: 13
                        backupStatus: pending

[6]
                        tblSpaceName: INDSPACE1
                          tblSpaceID: 7
                        backupStatus: pending

[7]
                        tblSpaceName: SYSCATSPACE
                          tblSpaceID: 0
                        backupStatus: pending

[8]
                        tblSpaceName: SL
                          tblSpaceID: 4
                        backupStatus: pending

[9]
                        tblSpaceName: MONITOR
                          tblSpaceID: 5
                        backupStatus: pending

[10]
                        tblSpaceName: HISTORY
                          tblSpaceID: 14
                        backupStatus: pending

[11]
                        tblSpaceName: SYSTOOLSPACE
                          tblSpaceID: 3
                        backupStatus: pending

[12]
                        tblSpaceName: DSMSPACE
                          tblSpaceID: 9
                        backupStatus: pending

[13]
                        tblSpaceName: DLSPACECOPY
                          tblSpaceID: 12
                        backupStatus: pending

        The next table space to be backed up:

[0]
            tblSpaceName: XMLSPACE1
              tblSpaceID: 6
            backupStatus: pending



Performance statistics:
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Parallelism       = 10
Number of buffers = 20
Buffer size       = 16781312 (4097 4kB pages)

BM#    Total      I/O      MsgQ      WaitQ      Buffers    Bytes
---  --------  --------  --------  --------    --------  --------
000  40811.03      0.00      0.00  40811.00           0         0
001  40811.03      0.00      0.00  40810.96           0         0
002  40811.03      0.00      0.00  40811.00           0         0
003  40811.03      0.00      0.00  40811.00           0         0
004  40811.03      0.00      0.00  40811.00           0         0
005  40811.03      0.00      0.00  40811.00           0         0
006  40811.03      0.00      0.00  40810.98           0         0
007  40811.03      0.00      0.00  40811.00           0         0
008  40811.03      0.00      0.00  40811.00           0         0
009  40811.04      0.00      0.00  40811.00           0         0
---  --------  --------  --------  --------    --------  --------
TOT         -         -         -         -           0         0

MC#    Total      I/O      MsgQ      WaitQ      Buffers    Bytes
---  --------  --------  --------  --------    --------  --------
000  73085.95      0.00      0.00      0.00           0         0
---  --------  --------  --------  --------    --------  --------
TOT         -         -         -         -           0         0


Size estimates:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
             Total size estimate (bytes): 3203172077568
Pre-adjusted total size estimate (bytes): 3203172077568
              Init data estimate (bytes): 4645780
              User data estimate (bytes): 3201899954176
               End data estimate (bytes): 1073735192
           Size estimate for MC1 (bytes): 3203172077568
 Size estimate for remaining MCs (bytes): 3203155300352


Progress Monitor:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
             Phase #: 1 of 1
    Total work units (bytes): 3203172077568
Completed work units (bytes): 0

Other Backup Statistics:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
     Database bufferpool flushing time: 0.00 seconds
Table space bufferpool flushing time 1: 0.00 seconds
Table space bufferpool flushing time 2: Not Recorded
Table space bufferpool flushing time 3: Not Recorded

Database recovery history file (db2rhist.asc) elapsed processing time: Not Recorded
Table space change history file (db2tschg.his) elapsed processing time: Not Recorded

No logs are included in this image.
```

Comment: What's the result of `db2pd -uti`? What do you see in the db2diag.log after the backup startup?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein can you look below? I've pasted info, that You'v asked for. BTW I've tried to force application no 39477 - it executes, but the application is still on the list, even after several minutes.

Comment: Mark, 
I've added output to your comment from my deleted answer to the end of the original question. 

Your comment:  
Please, edit your question with this information, and remove the answer. So, did we you right, that you see nothing in the outpuf of db2pd -db dbname -apinfo 39477 and db2pd -db dbname -barstats 14137? – 
Mark Barinstein
1 hour ago

Comment: So, we have a session doing backup, which doesn't want to be forced off. Unfortunately, IBM doesn't provide here any other solution except killing the instance as described at the [How to terminate BACKUP DATABASE command](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-how-terminate-backup-database-command) link.

Comment: Thank you. Will db2stop; dbstart be better than db2_kill in this particular situation?

Comment: You may try it first, of course, but `db2stop force` will hang highly likely.

Comment: Will db2start start without any issues? Also start hadr?

Comment: After crash recovery - yes, it should start normally.

Comment: So, I do: 

1. db2_kill (if db2stop force won't work).
2. db2start
3. db2 start hadr on db $DB as primary

That's all?

Comment: `db2gcf -k; ipclean -a; db2start; db2 activate db ${DB}`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I'll try it tomorrow and let know here.

Comment: It worked - crash recovery took some time, but DB is consistent and Tablespaces are in 0x0000 state. Thanks again!